# File upload HttpPostedFileBase null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, post, nullreferenceexception, httppostedfilebase

I'm uploading a file via a rest client to a asp.net mvc controller, I'm experiencing System.NullReferenceException as the response.

Here's my rest client generated code

```
POST /api/File/Upload HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8395
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 15b1c2a9-3809-461d-933f-d578074bcc8e
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW

------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="PicToUpload.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--
```

Here's my action method on the controller.

```
//POST api/File/Upload
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {

            try
            {
                if (file.ContentLength > 0) //NullReferenceException here
                {
                    FileOperations fops = new FileOperations();
                    await fops.UploadToAzureFileStorage(file);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                 return InternalServerError(ex);
            }

            return Ok();
        }
```

Comment: client generated code clearly displays that there is no file content, that is why you are getting the error